# how can I save NSMutableArray in to table while array has stored another array of different objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have an array, I want to save this in UITable, but it is not visible, my code is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [myArrayNew count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;
}
```

and this array is having some other array, not single objects,

Comment: How do you want to display the array of array values in UITableview?

Comment: all 3 elements in one row, I want like this

Comment: be sure u have set table's datasource and delegate. and then follow robin's instruction. thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you should code differently,

```
[myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

will return an array of objects , not the string.

**EDIT:**

You can use a sectioned tableview to display array of array.

So that code as follows,

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return [myArrayNew count];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[myArrayNew objectAtIndex:section]count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *cellValue = [[myArrayNew objectAtIndex:section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I have two values in an NSMutableArray, but I want to show both values in one single row, then the next two values in next single row, you got it Sir?

Comment: error is here that 'section' undeclared, now what is this section is Sir

Comment: sorry change it as indexPath.section

Comment: error: expected ']' before '.' token                                                   

this is error, when I put ur code as                               NSString *cellValue = [[myArrayNew objectAtIndex.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: NSString *cellValue = [[myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 0):

@Veer use something like this

```
NSArray *cellArray = [myArrayNew objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *cellValue = [cellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
return cell;
```

or something like this. If you show us what type of contents is in myArrayNew then we can can help you more.

EDIT: this just an example not the actual answer.

Comment: This will crash if cellArray count is less than myArrayNew count. index may become out of bound in this case.

Comment: Yes i know, but this is just an example not the actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

you have to store the values in one more array..and the second array object you can assign to a string..

Comment: Sir I have assigned it to an NSMutableArray, not a NSString, but still problem is same, that I can't show all two values in my NSMutableArray into a single row of my table